# Why VS 2010 does not see this library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

Why VS 2010 does not see this il library. I drag it into the solution and it does not see header file other way adding it seems impossible in VS.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to clean the project? Sometimes it also helps to generate a new project with the same files.

Comment: You may need to check if you external files are in the lookup path